My results from linear regression differs from my collegues despite having same data. Is this to be expected?
Long story short: Guy who did these calculations quit and did not leave any code behind. Now I am tasked with recreating the necessarry calculations to perform this years calculations - but my results always differ from his when I calculate the data from the previous year and that makes the boss unhappy.
What we know: The calculation is suppose to be a simple linear regression (so they've told me). We have a bunch of stations in the local area which each produce 365*24 (8760) data points every year. For each station there will be one linear regression model made with the data points of the station as y-values and the outside temperature at the time of the data point creation as the x-values. Using these models we then get a prediction value by inputting one specific temperature (same temperature for each regression).
I've made a couple linear regression implementations in Python and now also in C# using readily available libraries (SciKitLearn, MathNet.Numerics) and also just made the code from scratch. All of these calculations produce the same (give or take 1%) results - which all differ from "the golden standard" of the previous guys calculations by 1-10% even when our R2-scores are roughly the same. For example: Here the difference is 4% between us, which is unacceptable by my bosses standards




Output
R2




Ex-collegue
113
0,938


Me
108
0,927



Is this sort of difference to be expected from different implementations of linear regression, even when the given data is the same? Why have I not found an implementation of linear regression that mirrors my ex-collegues results more closely and what can I do about it?
I've tried making multiple implementations in Python and C#, hoping that my results would be essentially a mirror image of my ex-collegues results - but this was not the case and the boss is unhappy.
The code I am currently using and which gives the exact same results as MathNet.Numerics:
    public void Fit(double[] predictor_variables, double[] target_variables)
{
    var ssxy = predictor_variables.Zip(target_variables, (a, b) => a * b).Sum() - predictor_variables.Length * predictor_variables.Average() * target_variables.Average();
    var ssxx = predictor_variables.Zip(predictor_variables, (a, b) => a * b).Sum() - predictor_variables.Length * predictor_variables.Average() * predictor_variables.Average();

    Slope = ssxy / ssxx;
    Intercept = target_variables.Average() - Slope * predictor_variables.Average();
}


Unfortunately, I'm having some difficulty understanding your model. What are your predictor variables and what is your target variable? What does 'output' in the table mean?
You also do not specify what prediction error you're trying to minimize with your model (e.g. MAE, MSE, RMSE). Are you sure that it is consistent between you and your ex-collegue?

@user3500869 I'm sorry if I was not clear. The data points from the stations are the predicted/target/response variables; The temperatures are the explanatory/predictor variables. What I mean with "output" is the predicted value from the regression model given the "specific temperature" mentioned in my post, which is the coldest recorded temperature of the past couple of years. I'll update my post to include my code, in case that says anything worthwhile.

Even if your code was exactly the same as the other person's code, you may not achieve the same results, due to randomness (splitting the dataset if you do that). You could try adjusting the seed to try to get similar results to the other person's.
However, if you or the other person are doing any preprocessing with your data points, it would be harder to find out the exact preprocessing to do as you say you don't have the other person's code. You could try to experiment around with the preprocessing to try to replicate the other person's results.

There is no randomness in a standard linear regression model.

@MrMulliner I think the point he wants to make is the randomness in splitting the dataset (hold out a valid/test set, over-/subsample etc.), which we don't even know if the ex-colleague did or not. Same applies to any preprocessing steps which may (not) take place.

Besides, there is a chance that ex-colleague's solver is using SGD, in which randomness may affect.

Sebastian asks "is this sort of difference to be expected [...] even when the given data is the same?", and the phrasing of the question suggests they are using the same data split. It's true that the ex-colleague may be using SGD, but given the scale of the data (~8k datapoints per year, and I think we can assume an upper bound of decades on the age of the stations; one single predictor variable - temperature), this seems unlikely.

This could arise from several factors. First, consider how outliers might have been handled, as removing or adjusting them can significantly influence the regression model. Additionally, check if data scaling or transformations, such as normalization or log transformations, were applied to the input variables, as these can alter the regression coefficients. Even if you've been told that simple linear regression was used, there might still be implicit regularization(ridge /lasso) or adjustments involved. If possible, plot your results against your colleague's outputs and the actual data. Look for consistent patterns where your colleague’s regression lines are consistently above or below your lines, or if there are specific differences in intercept or slope. This could indicate that your colleague applied specific post-processing steps or domain knowledge adjustments in their code.

OLS linear regression is deterministic (insofar as computers are deterministic). There is a straightforward calculation to obtain the parameter estimates. In that regard, yes, you should obtain the exact same results as your former colleague.
However, there are so many ways to fit a linear regression, even on the same data. For instance, your colleague may have used a ridge, LASSO, or elastic net estimation procedure that penalizes the coefficients for being nonzero, with the hope being that there will be a better overall fit. The hyperparameters of these can be calculated through cross validation. With cross validation, there is a non-deterministic element in how to partition the data into folds. If you split the data differently than your colleague did, you are likely to find hypermeters that are at least slightly different, leading to different parameter estimates and different predictions. If your colleague didn't set a seed that fixes the partitioning of the data, then there is basically no hope to recover the exact same partitioning and getting the exact same results your colleague got. Your colleague may have just gotten a lucky break in the partitioning.
Your colleague may have performed stepwise selection of variables. While such an approach has its problems, it certainly can be done and is supported in software packages. If you don't know to do a stepwise selection procedure and which procedure your colleague used, I suppose you could run a search through the common options and see if any of them lead to the same results your colleague obtained. Then again, your colleague may have run a ridge, LASSO, or elastic net regression on the selected variables. I am not sure this makes much sense, but your colleague has shown poor data science practice by not leaving any code or documentation, so would you put yet another poor practice past that colleague?
Your colleague may have applied some pre-processing to the data that you are not, such as winsorizing variables to clip apparent outliers. Your colleague may have dropped outliers entirely and then reported the $R^2$ on the outlier-free data. No wonder those results are better than yours if the difficult points have been removed.
Your colleague may have estimated the coefficients by minimizng absolute loss instead of square loss, particularly if there are some extreme points.
Finally, not everyone even agrees on how to calculate $R^2$, particularly out-of-sample. In simple settings, the squared Pearson correlation between predicted and true values is equal to many other common calculations. If your colleague did a ridge regression, however, then such a calculation will not give the same answer as sklearn.metrics.r2_score in Python. It will be higher, and your former colleague got a higher $R^2$ score than you are obtaining. Out-of-sample, the situation gets even murkier, as there are issues with the r2_score calculation. Notably, if your colleague calculated as I discuss in the link, then r2_score is a lower bound on that calculation. Again, you are getting a lower $R^2$ score than your colleague.
Overall, yes, there are a huge number of reasons why your results may differ from those of your departed colleague. Chasing down the results of a colleague who you know has problematic work habits might not be the best use of your time. If your manager decides to manage you by tasking you with figuring out what your colleague did, you can decide if you want to push back on that or go through some of these ideas I've presented along with other ideas you think of or read in other answers here. Perhaps IT can dig through that colleague's equipment to see if any code or interactive commands are in the history, such as hitting the up arrow in the Anaconda shell or in RStudio.

TBH, this is going to be tough, as we do not know what preprocessing step(s) was done. And if this was not enough, we don't even know for sure if the model was really a standard linear regressor. Let's hope it is.
Assume it is simple linear regression, I would try in the following order:

Scaling: this is the most common preprocessing step. Try standardization/normalization.
Try different weights of L1/L2 regularization.

